# Angular JS: How to sum all variables inside @scope.object

Tags: object, sum

Angular JS: How to sum all variables inside `@scope.object`?

I have a object `$scope.Growth` with multiple variables inside.
How can I sum all of them in easiest way?

[image: $scope.Growth]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Object.values($scope.Growth)
  .filter(value => !isNaN(value))
  .reduce((sum, value) => sum + value, 0)
```

This works by

1. Getting an array of the values for each own property in the object
2. Filtering out any values which are not convertible to valid numbers
3. Summing all the values up by reducing the filtered array.

If you're in an older run time and don't have the `Object.values` function available to you, you can write it as follows

```
Object.keys($scope.Growth)
  .map(function (key) {return $scope.Growth[key];})
  .filter(function (value) {return !isNaN(value);})
  .reduce(function (sum, value) {return sum + value;}, 0)
```

Here is an example of it in action

```js
const $scope = {
  Growth: {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
  }
};

const sum = Object.values($scope.Growth)
  .filter(value => !isNaN(value))
  .reduce((sum, value) => sum + value, 0);
  
console.info(sum);
```

Note if you need to databind to the result in an AngularJS template, not mentioned in the question but suggestable from the name `$scope`, you would write something like

```js
(function() {

  AppController.$inject = ['$scope'];
  function AppController($scope) {
    $scope.Growth = {
      a: 1,
      b: 2,
      c: 3
    };
    $scope.growthSum = () => Object.values($scope.Growth)
      .filter(value => !isNaN(value))
      .reduce((sum, value) => sum + value, 0);
  }

  const app = angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller({
      AppController
    });

  angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('app'), [app.name], {
    ngStrictDi: true
  });
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">
</script>
<div id="app" ng-controller="AppController">
  {{growthSum()}}
</div>
```

Comment: @KevalRaj I added a version that is compatible with older runtimes. If that fails then the object is not as you have indicated

Comment: im getting syntax error in visual studio. Am I missing something? 
  Object.keys($scope.Growth).map(key => $scope.Growth[key]).filter(value => !isNaN(value)) .reduce((sum, value) => sum + value, 0)

Comment: @KevalRaj I just added a code snippet to the answer. You can click and run it and see that it works. You didn't mention a specific IDE in your question, but it works for me in Visual Studio and has done so for many years.

Comment: @KevalRaj I added an example with databinding

Comment: Then you have something wrong with your environment which I will point out, you did not mention in your question at all. If you click on the snippets above and run them, they run in any modern browser. I cannot answer a question that you did not ask.

Comment: Unhandled exception at line 42, column 297 in http://localhost:54238/Scripts/angular.min.js

0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$injector/modulerr?p0=R1_myApp&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.6.4%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DR1_myApp%0A%20%20%20at%20Anonymous%20function%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5

Comment: That is telling you that AnuglarJS is failing to load because there is no module registered with the name of the application you are bootstrapping or one of its dependencies. That has absolutely nothing to do with your question. Your question does not even mention AngularJS. I have demonstrated how you can sum the properties of an object. I even created an AngularJS application that uses the tequnique and you can run that app inside of the answer. If that is not enough, consider how little detail you provided.